# how to create an 2-Dimensional Array with string and double format

Tags: c#, arrays

I'd like to know if it's possible to create an 2D Array in the c# (not the format string) which contains tow columns. The first is Date (format string) and the second is Price (format double).

Here is my code

```
double [][]=Array[2][];

string[]=Date;

double[]=Prices;

Array[0]=Date;

Array[1]=Prices;
```

Comment: It is always good practice to create your own classes than mix types in arrays for transmitting compound data. Depending on your needs, a `struct` instead of a class may also work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to put `string` in a `double` array. I suggest to use another type, for example a `Tuple<double[], string[]>`.

```
Tuple<double[], string[]> t = new Tuple<double[], string[]>(Prices,  Data);

double[] prices = t.Item1;
string[] data = t.Item2;
```

But you could better create your own type, reflecting these properties.

```
public class YourClass
{
    public double[] Prices {get;set;}
    public string[] Data {get;set;}
}
```

And use it like this:

```
YourClass c = new YourClass() { Prices = prices, Data = data };
```

But maybe you want to combine the items:

```
public class PriceInfo
{
    public double Price {get;set;}
    public string Data {get;set;}
}
```

And just create a list of them:

```
List<PriceInfo> list = new List<PriceInfo>();
list.Add(new PriceInfo() { Price = 1d, Data = "abc" });
```

Comment: I personally would avoid a tuple like the plague for this kind of thing. Super unreadable. Creating your own type (like you suggest) is much more readable.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Agree. Added.

Comment: Indeed; tuples grant zero transparency in terms of data types. And seeing `something.Item7` in a code is truly horrifying.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have both types in an array, but it is not reconmended. You would have to declare an array of type `object` and assign your values to the array. But you would also have to do type casting anytime you reference those values.

```
object[][] array;
```

I suggest creating an object to contain your values and then have an array of that.

```
public class Container
{
     public string Date { get; set; }
     public double[] Prices { get; set; }
}

Container[] array;
array[0].Date = "7/14/15";
array[0].Prices[0] = 100.00;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative take on this.

It looks like you want to be able to look up prices for a given date. If that is the case, one way to solve is is by using a dictionary that maps dates to arrays of doubles:

```
var pricesByDate = new Dictionary<DateTime, double[]>();
```

They you can use to dictionary to find the prices for a particular date like so:

```
var prices = pricesByDate[myDateToLookU[];
```

A simple console app which demonstrates follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var pricesByDate = new Dictionary<DateTime, double[]>();

            var date1 = new DateTime(2015, 01, 01);
            var date2 = new DateTime(2015, 01, 02);
            var date3 = new DateTime(2015, 01, 03);

            pricesByDate[date1] = new[] { 1.01, 1.02, 1.03 };
            pricesByDate[date2] = new[] { 2.01, 2.02, 2.03, 2.04 };
            pricesByDate[date3] = new[] { 3.01, 3.02 };

            Console.WriteLine("Prices for {0}:", date2);

            var pricesForDate2 = pricesByDate[date2];

            foreach (double price in pricesForDate2)
                Console.WriteLine(price);

            Console.WriteLine("\nAll Dates and prices:");

            foreach (var entry in pricesByDate)
            {
                Console.Write("Prices for {0}: ", entry.Key.ToShortDateString());

                foreach (double price in entry.Value)
                    Console.Write(price + " ");

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd probably use a `List<double>` rather than a `double[]` for this, because it allows you to add and remove values after it's been created.